# Brightness doesn't change

Tags: laptop, brightness

At first my laptop didn't fully shutdown so I edited grub file GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset" and that worked pretty well. But, I found out that brightness no more changes. So, I tried editing grub file again GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=linux" but nothing changes.
To change the brightness I need to set the brightness I want then restart my laptop and then it opens with this brightness I've just set.
Note: I'm using Dell G15 5511.
Edit: I removed the added part and I set grub fill as default and brightness was working properly but the laptop isn't shutting down again

Comment: You're moving rather critical details, especially what Ubuntu product/release you're using. Your question deals with linux kernel options, thus release, and kernel are essential details, and if you're using a Ubuntu LTS release, which kernel stack you're using maybe required (*the default stack is set by the installation media, so if this is a recent install, telling us what you installed specifically may answer that if you don't know*).